# Android: OnItemClickListener returns the value of the last item

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

the code bellow was working so fine with me but now i don't know what's wrong with it!! whenever i click to an item it put the value of the last item to the intent! any idea?

```
 protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        customList=new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> appointement = result.get(i);
            String fromT = appointement.get("fromT");
            String toT = appointement.get("toT");
            String date = appointement.get("date");
            //int doctorid=Integer.parseInt(id.replaceAll("[\\D]",""));
            addAvailableAppoint(fromT, toT, date);
        }
        updateListView();
    }
}

private void addAvailableAppoint(final String fromT, final String toT, final String date) {
    customList.add(new AvailabilityList(fromT));
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("items", "fromt " + fromT + "tot: " + toT);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MakeAppointementActivity.this, AppointementActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Doctor's name", DoctorName);
            intent.putExtra("Doctor's infos", DoctorInfos);
            intent.putExtra("fromT", fromT);
            intent.putExtra("toT", toT);
            intent.putExtra("date", date);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

// split new function for update listview
private void updateListView(){
    ArrayAdapter adapter=new DoctorAvailabilityAdapter(MakeAppointementActivity.this,R.layout.list_items,customList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** You don't need to set the click listener for each new item in your list.
Just set it once, outside the for-loop.

**2)** Try to use a Model class for your adapter that contains all the data: 
`fromT` , `toT` and `date`. Because as i see, your `AvailabilityList` contains only `fromT`.

**3)** As mentioned in @CommonsWare answer, in `onItemClick` try to find the appropriate object using `position` or `id` in parameters.

eg:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       AvailabilityList item = (AvailabilityList)parent.getItem(position);
       //Then from your item you can get the data: fromT , toT and date
    }
```

Comment: i understand (1) & (3).                                                                                         for (2) in the listview i want to only display **fromT** and send **toT** & **date** through the intent, that's why!

Comment: While you'll send your data when you click an item, you need to get the whole data from that item, that's why its better if you put `fromT` , `toT` and `date` in your model.--- For (3): in `onItemClick()` method, you have the `id` and the `position` of the clicked item, you can use them to get your item (model) from adapter data.

Answer (score 0):

> whenever i click to an item it put the value of the last item to the intent!

You are ignoring all of the parameters to `onItemClick()`. If you are expecting your data to vary, you need to find the appropriate data in your collection, via `position` or `id`.

Comment: Your answer wasn't clear to me at first but now i understand! thanks